# Devise Authenticate User for AJAX Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

What is the best way of handling redirects in an AJAX call that require users (through devise)? I wanted to do something like:

```
$('#love').click(function() {
  $.get('/item/#{item.id}', function(data) {
    if (data.redirect) { window.location.replace(data.redirect); return; }
  }); 
});
```

However, I'm not sure how to get devise before filter (authenticate user) handle the 'js' request format. Any ideas?

Comment: I would just open an other page in a hidden iframe to do the authentication and other server side work, the page can them call a js function on the parent with it's response and you can redirect depending on the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in your `ApplicationController` file to redirect via AJAX:

```
  # allows redirecting for AJAX calls as well as normal calls
  def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
    if request.xhr?
      render(:update) {|page| page.redirect_to(options)}
    else
      super(options, response_status)
    end
  end
```

So essentially, if a request is made via AJAX and the controller action (or a before_filter) says to redirect to a sign in page, this will redirect the page for that AJAX call.

If you store the request data in a cookie, you might be able to fulfill the request after the user is properly authenticated.

Answer (score 3):

Devise has special option just for that: `http_authenticatable_on_xhr`
You might find [this devise issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/534) relevant.

Also, I really advice against using redirects with XHR requests. You'll find yourself in a world of pain once you try using that with firefox. Before Gecko 7.0 firefox wouldn't save headers from original request when following an XHR redirect.

According to [developer.mozilla.org XMLHttpRequest page:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest)

> From Gecko 7.0 headers set by setRequestHeader() are sent with the request when following a redirect. Previously these headers would not be sent.

Comment: To elaborate slightly. When I stumbled upon this I was getting normal redirect instead of loading a partial via xhr. Took me some precious time before I realized that it was not my code misbehaving.